# kableExtra functions in R return latex errors when compiling rmarkdown file to PDF document in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to knit a rmarkdown file to PDF file which contains **kableExtra** functions like:

- *kable_styling*
- *column_spec*
- *add_header_above*

However I am always getting the following error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.184 \end{tabular}}


pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
Ejecución interrumpida
```

One easy example that I am executing is:

````
```
---
output:
 pdf_document:
   keep_tex: yes
classoption: table
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
---

```{r results='asis'}
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
require(kableExtra)
print(kable(head(cars),"latex")%>%kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", 
"bordered"))
  %>%column_spec(column=1:2,width = "0.5in") %>%
      kable_styling(c("striped", "bordered"),latex_options = 
"scale_down")%>% add_header_above(c(" "=7,
"Absolute"=1,"Relative"=1,"Absolute"=1,"Relative"=1,
"Absolute"=1,"Relative"=1,"Absolute"=1,"Relative"=1,"Absolute"=1,
"Relative"=1))%>%
add_header_above(c(" "= 1,"Non-weighted"=1,"Weighted"=1,"Non- 
weighted"=1,"Weighted"=1,"Non-weighted"=1,
"Weighted"=1,"Weighted"=2,"Non-weighted"=2,"Weighted"=2,"Non- 
weighted"=2,"Weighted"=2))%>%
add_header_above(c("Theoretical Values"= 1,"First-Order Predicted 
Value"=2,"Second-Order Predicted Value"=2,
"Third-Order Predicted Value"=2,
"Non-linearity 1st Order"=2,"Non-linearity 2nd Order"=4,"Non-linearity 3rd 
Order"=4)))
````

```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I would appreciate whatever clue!

Answer (score 1):

You are telling `kableExtra` not to load the LaTeX packages (why?), so you have to do this yourself. The features you are using require `array`, `float` and `xcolor` with the `table` option. One difficulty is that `fancyvrb` v3.0 already loads `xcolor` with [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53393826/8416610). You can circumvent this by supplying `table` as a class option:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
classoption: table    
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{float}
---


```{r results='asis'}
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
require(kableExtra)
print(kable(head(cars),"latex") %>%column_spec(column=1:2,width = "0.5in"))
```

```{r results='asis'} 
print(kable(head(cars),"latex")%>%kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "bordered")))
```
````

Comment: @LauraSantularioVerdú Please [edit] your question to include such information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is true that I 'd forgotten the YALM so I 've added now. 

The thing is that it is that now it works for function column_spec() but not for kable_styling(). I write you the code I have problems with:

---
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
---

```{r results='asis'}

options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
require(kableExtra)
print(kable(cars,"latex")%>%kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "bordered")))
```

Comment: What error(s) do you get? Please add code to your question, since it is unreadable in a comment. Also please build a [mcve] instead of including code and the full YAML header separately.

Comment: @LauraSantularioVerdú Thanks, please see my updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I appreciate a lot. Doing your proposals has helped me a lot. Even this, I found some issues again. You can see my updated question.

Comment: @LauraSantularioVerdú Which other issues? The "Unknown float option 'H'" is already handled in my answer.

Comment: Sorry @Ralf Stubner, I am talking about another problem. It is now updated in the question

Comment: @LauraSantularioVerdú The new code does not make sense. You seem to add way more headers than your table has columns. Also, please avoid [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). By now my answer looks completely wrong, even though it answers your previous questions.

Comment: Thank very much for your help @Ralf Stubner. I have already solve my problem thanks to your help. And I have to apologized for changing the question so many times but I am completely new at Stack Overflow and I do not know how to write code in comments.

Comment: @LauraSantularioVerdú You are welcome. Consider accepting the answer if it hrlped you, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. From my point of view, updated code should always go into the question, since comments do not offer the necessary formating capabilities. However, you should keep the original question intact such that existing answers do not look "out of place".

Comment: You are right @Ralf Stubner, I appreciate your comment and I will improve this for my next time!